# gcloud crashed (UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: gcloud

> Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK! Run "gcloud -h" to get the list of
>
> ### available commands.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud init Welcome! This
>   command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.
>
> Your current configuration has been set to: [default]
>
> You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
>   gcloud init --skip-diagnostics
>
> Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
>   Checking network connection...done. Reachability Check passed. Network
>   diagnostic (1/1 checks) passed.
>
> ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character u'\xe7' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> If you would like to report this issue, please run the following
>   command:   gcloud feedback
>
> To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
>   gcloud info --run-diagnostics

I don't know what to do... I just want to use the sdk but I can't init it...

Comment: Can you look in your logs to see what might have gone wrong? The location of the logs directory can be found by running `gcloud info`.

Running `gcloud init` is a good way to get your Cloud SDK set up for use. However it is not required, you can use the Cloud SDK without it. You will just have to set up your account using `gcloud auth login` and your project using `gcloud config set project NAME_OF_YOUR_PROJECT`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is the log : 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al4u8hoba_q0m4d3Wx0SHWemeCjWEQ
I guess the error is due to the 'ç' in my firstname ... but how to make it works then ?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the file which gave error , edit the .py file to add following lines

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try edit the code in `google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/socks/__init__.py`(`google-cloud-sdk` is the archive you downloaded to install google cloud sdk) in line 262:

```
req = req + struct.pack(">H", destport)
```

to

```
if isinstance(req, unicode):
    req = req.encode('UTF-8')
req = req + struct.pack(">H", destport)
```

reference: https://c11e.wodemo.com/gcloud-crashed-unicodedecodeerror

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was removing an accent ('é') from a folder in the path of my project. Hope it can help someone since I didn't find this solution after googling it for hours.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I also had a special character in my project name. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this similar error every time I ran a gcloud command after a crash:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 1: invalid start byte`

The solution was to delete this file:

`~/.config/gcloud/gce`

Don't ask me why that works or what that files does, I don't know (if you do, please let me know), but it gets recreated on the next command run and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a special character in the folders of the current directory. After changing the current directory, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As you’ve noticed that the error is due to a non-ASCII character in the username. As a workaround, you can set the CLOUDSDK_CONFIG environment variable to a path that contains only ASCII characters.

Comment: that's right, I've set `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG ` to `C:\config` and initialized gcloud